# gas station payment preapproval process

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm relatively new to the PayPal API. I'm looking for a way to achieve pre-approval process like gas stations. I don't know if it's possible. Please give me some ideas good folks!

Problem: In a transaction at time *t0*, payment sender commits and pre-approves payment up to $*X* maximum to receiver at *t1* where *t0* < *t1*. Depending on actual usage, the amount charged to the sender's account at *t1* is $*Y* where *Y* <= *X*.

Example: I walk into a typical US gas station to prepay for $40 worth of gas. I may end up only filling $30 worth, so my account is only charged $30 after the fill.

Q: Is the Adaptive Preapproval payment sufficient to achieve this? Do I need to go through a special authorization process to obtain privilege for using this API?

Many thanks you good folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just called an authorization, and pretty much all of PayPal's payment products (Classic, Express Checkout, Payflow, Adaptive, REST, etc) support it.

Comment: Thank you. I found the link at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/auth-capture/